# C++ bitwise copy of object failing? Why?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, copy-constructor

This question is regarding bitwise copying of class objects.
Why is constructor not called, instead destructor is called in below code ? 
The output is as

**HowMany h2 = f(h);  // No constructor get;s called here..**

```
after construction of h: objectCount = 1
x argument inside f(): objectCount = 1
~HowMany(): objectCount = 0
after call to f(): objectCount = 0
~HowMany(): objectCount = -1
~HowMany(): objectCount = -2




class HowMany {
    static int objectCount;
public:
    HowMany() { objectCount++; }
    static void print(const string& msg = "") {
        if(msg.size() != 0) cout << msg << ": ";
        cout << "objectCount = "
            << objectCount << endl;
    }
    ~HowMany() {
        objectCount--;
        print("~HowMany()");
    }
};

int HowMany::objectCount = 0;
// Pass and return BY VALUE:

HowMany f(HowMany x) {
    x.print("x argument inside f()");
    return x;
}

int main() {
    HowMany h;
    HowMany::print("after construction of h");
    HowMany h2 = f(h);
    HowMany::print("after call to f()");
} ///:~
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, C++ does not have "bitwise copying". The default copying mechanism is implemented by compiler-provided *copy constructor*. Compiler-provided copy constructor recursively copies each data member by invoking each data member's specific copying semantics. The end result might inded look like a "bitwise copy" in some cases, but nevertheless the language does not use such a low-level concept.

Secondly, the constructor that is called in this case is, again, *copy constructor*. It's signature is

```
HowMany::HowMany(const HowMany&)
```

This constructor is provided by the compiler and it is indeed called, yet you are simply not counting it. That is why your `objectCount` counter shows disbalanced result.

Answer (score 2):

Because copy constriuctor is missing .
you must  incrementing in copy constructor as well

add this line too

```
HowMany(const HowMany& r) { objectCount++; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having the issue that in your function `f()` the copy-constructor is called, which is not the normal constructor. When the function goes out of scope the the destructor will be invoked.
Provide a copy constructor like

```
HowMany::HowMany(const HowMany& other){
 objectCount++;
}
```

and this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a copy constructor  for HowMany  . By default a copy constructor would be created by compiler for you and you would not feel it getting called.